# how to add multiple image extensions in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

Can any one guide me how to add multiple image extensions in a JavaScript value?

Here is the code:

```
<script>
  window.onload = init;

  var car;
  function init(){

    car = $('.car').ThreeSixty({
      totalFrames: 52, 
      endFrame: 52, 
      currentFrame: 1, 
      imgList: '.threesixty_images', 
      progress: '.spinner', 
      imagePath:'assets/', 
      filePrefix: '', 
      ext: '.png',   # here i need to add image extensions like jpeg, png , gif etc..
      height: 1000,
      width: 447,
      responsive: true

    });

  }
</script>
```

Comment: `ext: '.png.jpeg.png.gif'` is "adding multiple image extensions" but that's probably not gonna help because we have no idea what `ThreeSixty` is.

Comment: or `ext: ['.png','.jpeg','.png','.gif']` if it expects a single value or an array. But searching for ThreeSixty shows [this project](https://github.com/creativeaura/threesixty-slider) which by the documentation only seems to be a single value. You would need to modify the plugin to make it use multiple extensions

Comment: Look at the documentation of the library you are using?

Comment: @PatrickEvans can you guide me to modify plugin...

Comment: That is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow

Comment: @Muhammed it makes no sense, you cannot create such a generic plugin which supports multiple extensions for a single frameset

Comment: However, check out my answer ThreeSixty does support an array of images, which makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThreeSixty does not support multiple extensions, but it supports `imgArray`

```
car = $('.car').ThreeSixty({
    totalFrames: 52,
    endFrame: 52,

    imgArray: ["/images/image1.png", "/images/image2.jpg", ... ]

    currentFrame: 1, 
    imgList: '.threesixty_images', 
    progress: '.spinner', 
    height: 1000,
    width: 447,
    responsive: true    
});
```

https://github.com/creativeaura/threesixty-slider/blob/master/src/threesixty.js#L863

Comment: Np, I hope you understood why its not possible, however, you could theoretically patch the library to support an array of image paths, this should't be a hard task to solve.

Comment: one more thing there in the plugin imagepath is used. is it possible to render all images using an array? if not what would be the possible solution to use PHP and MySQL to render my images. thank you

Comment: Yes, like I mentioned this should be possible. Could be solved in a couple of hours I guess, just create a fork, and try it

Comment: @Muhammed seams like they are supporting `imgArray` already but not mentioning it in the docs, sometimes you just have to read the code ;)

Comment: could you help me in solving this ??

Comment: I am glad to help you

Comment: sry, @Muhammed I don't know what's wrong with your setup, I can just tell you, that I even never worked with this ThreeSixty. I think it should't be a problem to check the error messages and to debug it locally.

Comment: All the code of ThreeSixty is about 600 LOC with lots of comments

Comment: Anyhow thanks, @webdeb to spend your valuable time on this question.